# Вывод меток определенного цвета в Google Maps при выборе их в меню

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api, google-maps

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы выбрав пункты в меню, выводились метки для этого пункта, а все остальные метки удалялись, а если убираю пункт, то чтобы все метки возвращались. Собрал версию которая только убирает значки для выбранного меню. Помогите, кто понимает в работе с Google Maps API.

```js
var map = {};

function initialize() {

  var mapProp = {
    center: {
      lat: -25.363,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    zoom: 8,
    markers: []
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.363,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'blue',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker1);
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.664,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'green',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker2);
  var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.365,
      lng: 131.144
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'red',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker3);
  var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.366,
      lng: 131.244
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'blue',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker4);
  var marker5 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.565,
      lng: 131.144
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'red',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker5);
  var marker6 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.666,
      lng: 131.244
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'green',
  });
  map.markers.push(marker6);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.markerBtn').bind('click', function(el) {
    var catToToggle = $(this).attr('data-category');
    $.each(map.markers, function() {
      if (this['category'] == catToToggle) {
        this.setVisible(!this.getVisible());
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.islands#redIcon {color: red;}
#name {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px; "></div>
<div class="markerBtn" data-category="green">
  <a href="#" id="name" style="color: green;">1 пункт</a>
</div>
<div class="markerBtn" data-category="red">
  <a href="#" id="name" style="color: red;">2 пункт</a>
</div>
<div class="markerBtn" data-category="blue">
  <a href="#" id="name" style="color: blue;">3 пункт</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну так в том примере, откуда Вы это взяли, все достаточно неплохо объяснено. У вас метки меню, а там категории. Разницы никакой. У каждого пункта меню должно быть прописано, какого цвета метки включать. При нажатии на пункт меню проходите по массиву меток и включаете или выключаете их...

Comment: @cyadvert, как реализовать этот самый проход и включение/выключение?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос html код меню, пожалуйста

Comment: @cyadvert, добавил :)

Comment: Ну так вроде бы ничего и не поменялось. Все должно работать. В чем проблема-то? Что пытались сделать? что не работает?

Comment: @cyadvert, сейчас, выбирая пункт в меню, удаляются и добавляются(при втором нажатии) метки которые относятся к этому пункту.Остальные остаются на своем месте, мне же нужно чтобы при выборе пункта, метки этого пункта выводились, а все остальные удалялись. При повторном нажатии на этот пункт снова появлялись все метки

Comment: Ну в таком случае это имеет мало отношения к GoogleMaps. Это чистый `javascript`. Вам стоит обратить внимание на код внутри `$.each(map.markers, function() {});`. Он пролистывает через все имеющиеся маркеры. И вам надо его поменять так, чтобы при совпадении маркер включался или выключался, а при не совпадении - исчезал. Это простейшая логика. Функции `this.getVisible()` и `this.setVisible()` Вам помогут. Первая проверяет включен (показывается) ли маркер. Вторая - включает или выключает его.

Comment: @cyadvert, я сделал такой код `$.each(map.markers, function() { this.setVisible(!this.getVisible());
      if (this['category'] == catToToggle) {
        this.setVisible(!this.getVisible());`, если выбрать допустим 1 пункт, то он удаляет все метки и выводит только 1 пункта, при повторном нажатии на пункт, все метки возвращаются. Но если включен 1 пункт и нажать на другой пункт(допустим 2), то выводится метки 3 пункта(метки 1 удаляются), при повторном нажатии метки 1 пункта, 2 пункт никак не отображается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша задача имеет мало отношения к `GoogleMaps`. Это чистый `javascript`.

Во-первых, Вам надо хранить "состояние" каждой метки меню (включен/выключен).
А во-вторых, стоит обратить внимание на код внутри `$.each(map.markers, function() {});`. Он пролистывает через все имеющиеся маркеры, и Вам надо его поменять так, чтобы при совпадении маркер включался или выключался, а при не совпадении - исчезал.

Функции `getVisible()` и `setVisible()` Вам помогут.
Первая проверяет включен (показывается) ли маркер. Вторая - включает или выключает его.

Вот, что нужно сделать:
Сначала для каждого элемента меню надо добавить данные состояния. Добавьте `data-state="off"` вот так:

```
<div class="markerBtn" data-state="off" data-category="red">
```

Все метки изначально выключены.

Ну и изменить сам js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.markerBtn').bind('click', function(el) {
    var catToToggle = $(this).attr('data-category'); /* категория нажатой метка */
    var catState = $(this).attr('data-state'); /* статус нажатой метки */
    /* сразу меняем статус нажатой метки. Было on - делаем off, и наоборот */
    if (catState=='on') {
      $(this).attr('data-state', 'off');
    } else {
      $(this).attr('data-state', 'on');
    }
    /* теперь проверяем все маркеры подряд и прячем или показываем в зависимости от категории нажатой метки и ее состояния */
    $.each(map.markers, function() {
      if (this['category'] == catToToggle) {
        if (catState=='on') { /* проверяем состояние метки */
          /* включена - показываем маркер */
          this.setVisible(true);
        } else {
          this.setVisible(false);
        }
      } else {
        this.setVisible(false); /* это маркер другой категории - прячем */
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Комментарии вставил прямо в код...

Замечание: в зависимости от того, какая у Вас версия jQuery вместо `.attr()` скорее всего везде надо будет поставить `.prop()`.

Comment: Я исправил немного на `if (this['category'] == catToToggle) {
    this.setVisible(true);
    } else {
 this.setVisible(!this.getVisible());
    }` и теперь оно выводит метки как нужно, но осталась проблема с тем, что если я нажму на другой пункт, при включенном этом, то покажутся два других, а этот исчезнет, а хотелось бы, если возможно, что если включен 1 пункт и переключаешься на 2. Выводились только метки 2 пункта.

Comment: Такое работает если вместо `this.setVisible(!this.getVisible());` поставить `this.setVisible(false);`, но при повторном нажатии на пункт тогда не выводит все метки со всех пунктов.

Comment: Ну тогда надо хранить состояние метки. Ответ изменен.